# return word if the word is in a list string

Tags: python, string, find

I want to return the city in my address column, if the city is in my list_cities.

```
Cities = ['Los Angeles','New York']
Address = ['New York 123 ave unit 804','Los Angeles 567 ave unit 701']

if any(city in address for city in Cities):
    print ()
```

I want a return of ['New York','Los Angeles'], is there any way i can do this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can iterate over `Cities` instead:

```
Cities = ['Los Angeles','New York']
Address = ['New York 123 ave unit 804','Los Angeles 567 ave unit 701']
final_cities = [i for i in Cities if any(i in b for b in Address)]
```

For a solution sorted based on position in `Address`:

```
new_Address = {a:[c for c, d in enumerate(Address) if a in d] for a in Cities}
final_address = map(lambda x:x[0], sorted({a:b for a, b in new_Address.items() if b}.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1]))
```

Output:

```
['New York', 'Los Angeles']
```

Comment: Thank you! What if i want the order to be ['New York', 'Los Angeles'], since the order of this one is based on Cites, so it turn out to be ['Los Angeles','New York'].